# Fill Concavity in 3D Triangular Mesh (pyvista)

Tags: python, 3d, vtk, open3d, pyvista

I am currently working with some ship-hull models. All of model are mini-sized (15×15×15 cm) with a thickness of 1 mm.

I want to calculate the wetted area that are submerged in water, with mass of the model calculated as `volume * 1.118e-4`. Then the displacement should be `volume * 1.118e-4 / 1.0`. We can convert this problem to it's easier version: if I slice the model at z-direction in arbitrary position, how can I calculate its volume (with concavity on top filled but preserve anywhere else)?

The model is linked here: https://wwm.lanzouw.com/iWWBW0eti0zc

[image]

[image: Example Model]

I have attempted to just convert them into convex hulls, but that will fill some other concavities that I would like to keep.

Comment: Which button do I need, 电信下载, 联通下载, or 普通下载?! I've ended up pressing random buttons and downloading something, but it's bad form to link to third-party content on Stack Overflow, let alone one that doesn't have a single word in English.

Comment: I first wanted to suggest `clip_closed_surface`, but then I realised that's not what you need. There's `fill_holes` which can give results that _look_ like what you need, but don't give you a manifold mesh, so I suspect the volume based on that would be bogus.

Comment: Take a look at vespa: https://gitlab.kitware.com/vtk-cgal/vespa